# Autofill data for iPad

Tags: ios, mdm, meraki-api

I am working on trying to configure an iPad to clear autofill text boxes after a page refresh.

This is a customer service iPad meant for payment of bills, the device is managed and supervised by Cisco Meraki MDM and is currently set in single app mode. When attempting to use Chrome or Safari, in either standard or incognito mode, the device retains the name and account number of the previous customer.

Closing the tab and re-entering the link does provide the proper solution but we are looking for an automatic solution to this

Attempted multiple browsers
Checked standard and incognito mode
Attempted to block all cookies which prevented the site to open the account and pay invoices
Attempted inputting Chrome MDM policies, no success

Comment: The fact that closing and reopening the web site clears the data. suggests that it is probably functionality built in to that web site. It is unlikely that you can change it on the iPad side.